# external jar adding to eclipse project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, jar

I'm trying to add external JAR file to eclipse android project.
JAR package have config.xml and resources/ folder - where to add them? Because I`m getting error:

```
System.out Error: Could'nt load configuration file ./config.xml
```

I've tried to copy resources and config.xml to assets/ folder - but it did`nt help.

Comment: How are you trying to load the configuration file? Please post some of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In android way is

```
right click on project -->Properties -->Java build patch ---> Libraries tab ---> Add External JARs
```

But the main thing while adding external jar,remember it should be in same folder as it is project

Answer (score 0):

Through this act orders and actions, first right click on the project name in Package Explorer, then open the properties window:

```
Resources ---> Java build patch ---> Libraries tab ---> Add External JARs
```

Comment: I can include only .JAR file there, but I need include and config.xml and resources/ folders

Comment: @Dikobraz Using add external class folder.